# WP RSS Aggregator doesn’t import the WordPress RSS Feed?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, rss, feed

I want to integrate the »[WP RSS Aggregator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/)« plugin on my site. However, the plugin does not accept my others WordPress site’s feed, although it seems to be valid, when I check it with a RSS validator. What is wrong?

http://lebensraum-permakultur.de/feed/

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: do you get an error in console or in plugin? I see your link is not `https` could it be CORS or CSP blocking??

Comment: Hmm, when I install the plugin and pass through the setup process, it just won't accept my RSS and considers it as invalid. Nothing more. 

However, if I pass through the plugin's menu and add the feed URL, it works. Strange!